# How to get right database owner?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In my program I need to create a new database and then copy both data and the users from my old database.

To get databases owners from the old database I use

```
Select suser_sname(owner_sid) 
from sys.databases 
where name = '.....'
```

For databases which have user `dbo` with login name `sa` I get different answers.

Some databases return `sa` but some other databases return the user with Windows authentication (me) but I need only SA.

Could someone tell me why and how can I fix it ?

Thank you.

Comment: your question is not clear or maybe is the wrong question because there is nothing to fix. you get the owner and for some db is SA and for other db is someone else. why you want to get only/always SA? if the owner is not SA you will not get SA and this is correct. to me looks like your expectation (owner is always SA) is not correct.

Comment: The problem is if I look in dbo user login name is sa (for all al databases). But if I use

Comment: Select suser_sname(owner_sid) 
from sys.databases 
where name = '.....'
 I get sometimes 'SA' and sometimes the user with Windows authentication. Sid-s are different.

Answer (score 1):

What's there to fix?

You use the right query (`Select suser_sname(owner_sid) from sys.databases where name =...`) and you are getting exactly what you're supposed to get. The database owner is the original login (Windows user when using integrated auth) that created the database. This information is carried across database moves (attach, restores).

Comment: Actually I can verify that restoring the database does not carry the original database owner if you are restoring as a different database name; only if you are restoring the original database (e.g. `WITH REPLACE`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you mean that if I restore a customers database I become a db_Owner for this database?